# Calcular mínimo, promedio y porcentaje de un conjunto de valores

Tags: c, codeblocks

Hola buen día tengo que realizar este ejercicio y no comprendo como iniciar a plantearlo o sea como calcular el promedio de lluvias en todo el mes, porcentaje de días sin lluvia y el día que menos llovió.

> Se dispone de un informe meteorológico en el cual se ingresan los registros de
>   las lluvias del mes de mayo del año 2020 en la provincia de Corrientes que
>   consta de:
>
> - Numero de día (1..31)
> - Cantidad de lluvia (en mm >=0)
>
> Finaliza el ingreso de datos cuando se digite como numero de día el ultimo
>   digito del DNI del alumno que realiza el ejercicio + 40, es decir si el DNI termina en 3, al digitar 43
>
> Determinar e informar
>
> 1. el promedio de lluvia en todo el mes de estudio
> 2. el porcentaje de días sin lluvias
> 3. el día del año que menos llovió indicando día y cantidad de mm (no
>      considerar los ceros). El menor es único
>
> Se deben validar el número de día ingresado, no permitiendo un valor fuera del
>   rango establecido y la cantidad de mm ingresada no debe ser menor a cero.

Esto es lo que llegué a realizar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int ndia, cantlluvia, diamenoslluvia ;
    float promlluvia, porcentajedia ;

    do
    {
        printf("Ingresar el numero de dia : ");
        scanf("%d", &ndia);
    }
    while ( (ndia<0||ndia>32) && ndia != 46 );

    while (ndia != 46)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Ingrese la cantidad de lluvia en mm : ");
            scanf("f", &cantlluvia);
        }
        while (cantlluvia>=0);

        printf ("EL PROMEDIO DE LLUVIA EN TODO EL MES DE ESTUDIO ES : %f",  );
        printf ("EL PORCENTAJE DE DIAS SIN LLUVIAS ES : %f",  );
        printf ("EL DIA DEL AÑO QUE MENOS LLOVIO ES : %d Y LOS MM FUERON %f",  );

    }
}
```

Comment: "*Esto es lo que llegué a realizar*": No has hecho nada de lo que pedía ejercicio. ¿Podrías poner qué has intentado?